# Macro resolution address

Tags: c

```
#define PLAINTEXT_TARGET "plaintext"
if( strstr(PLAINTEXT_TARGET, optarg) == PLAINTEXT_TARGET )
    /* ... */
```

Does the C language guarantee that `PLAINTEXT_TARGET` above compiles into a single instance?  If the compiler may produce two instances of the macro string then the conditional above is misleading and can be false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros do simple textual replacement. The preprocessor replaces every occurrence of `PLAINTEXT_TARGET` with `"plaintext"`, after that the compiler looks at the result and compiles that.

So the compiler sees two string literals and it's not guaranteed that those won't be stored separately (see Alok's answer for the according quote from the standard). The code is indeed misleading, it would be more reasonable to declare `PLAINTEXT_TARGET` as a constant:

```
const char* const PLAINTEXT_TARGET = "plaintext";
```

Comment: Ahh! Your answers reference each other! I can't stop going back and forth between them!

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not guaranteed by the standard.  The standard says this about "string literals" (6.4.5p6):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values.

*These arrays* refers to the array of `char` created from a literal string in translation phase 7.

Since you are using a macro, the code seen by the compiler is:

```
if( strstr("plaintext", optarg) == "plaintext" )
```

When `optarg` is `"plaintext"`, the code reduces to

```
if("plaintext" == "plaintext")
```

As mentioned above, this is not guaranteed to be true in C.

So, you must use `strcmp()` instead of checking the pointers for equality, or, as in the other answer, define a `char *` pointer to use instead of the macro.